# Showing Grizzly exceptions in Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, grizzly

When launching a simple REST interface with Eclipse using the `jersey-container-grizzly2-http` Maven dependency version 2.13, I do not get any exceptions shown after triggering errors in the browser. Other log output gets shown in the console just fine, but Exceptions just get swallowed.

I created an Exception handler which is neither instantiated or called:

```
package mypackage.rest;
@Provider
class ExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
{
    @Override public Response toResponse(Throwable t)
    {
        System.out.println("toResponse called");
        t.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(t.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

The Grizzly Server construction:

```
package mypackage.rest;
public class GrizzlyHttpUtil
{
    public static final URI     baseURI = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(10010).build();

    public static HttpServer startThisServer()
    {
        ResourceConfig resCon = new ResourceConfig().packages("mypackage.rest");
        return server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseURI, resCon);
    }
}
```

The REST API class

```
package mypackage.rest;
@Path("")
public class Rest
{
  @GET @Path("datasets") @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public static String datasets()
  {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

**Update**
I got it to work with `resCon.register(ExceptionHandler.class);`. Why is that necessary? Why does ResourceConfig().packages(...) not handle this on its own?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had to solve the same problem. Here is my initialization code that convinces Grizzly HTTP server to display errors: http://source.apidesign.org/hg/bck2brwsr/rev/18ae4fbcfb87

```
Logger l = Logger.getLogger("org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler");
l.setLevel(Level.FINE);
l.setUseParentHandlers(false);
ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
ch.setLevel(Level.ALL);
l.addHandler(ch);
```

I am using Grizzly 2.3.3